# How To Joomla Install in WAMP SERVER 2.2?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

**Hello** 
I am using joomla insttalation in WAMP Server 2.2 installation all are the complate, after that i RUN joomla this type of error occur in home page how to remove that.....plz help me

NOTICE:Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\joomlawebsite\components\com_banners\models\banners.php on line 44

Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\joomlawebsite\components\com_banners\models\banners.php on line 45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a 5.4 version of PHP, try downgrading to 5.3 (that should fix the issue as per [this Joomla thread](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=725046).)

Comment: just install the 5.3 version of wamp. Or you could also try setting error_reporting so that it doesnt show notices but there may be more serious issues with it not sure